# Filtering the content inserted by an iframe in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I am using an iframe in an Angular app to insert a document from a static website. My iframe currently looks like this:

```html
<iframe src="{{aTrustedURL}}"></iframe>
```

I want to filter the content that is inserted so that all html links are opened in an external browser to the app.

The filter I want to use looks like this:

```js
.filter('hrefToJS', function ($sce, $sanitize) {
    return function (text) {
        var regex = /href="([\S]+)"/g;
        var newString = $sanitize(text).replace(regex, "onClick=\"window.open('$1', '_blank', 'location=yes')\"");
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(newString);
    }
});
```

.

I can't work out how to apply the filter to the content loaded by the iframe

Comment: I get the impression that iframe is on another domain...in which case you can't access inside it at all due to *same origin policy*. Also...why wouldn't you just use `target` on the `<a>`. replacing strings doesn't make as much sense as either changing attributes or adding event listeners

Comment: You can't control really anything in an iframe from another domain due to same origin policy. You cannot even manipulate DOM elements displayed in the iframe. If whomever built the other site did not include any options to open links in a browser outside the app - pretty sure you will be out of luck.

Comment: My problem is that the other domain contains some javascript that generates some html with links in it and I need the links to open a browser outside of my app. I don't have any control over the generated HTML as this is done by Disqus.